# How can I defer setting of store in redux until after the client is hydrated when using SSR?

Tags: react-redux, server-side-rendering

I am working on a React+Redux+Redux-Toolkit application that started from the official [vite-template-redux template](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-templates/tree/master/packages/vite-template-redux).

I added server-side rendering (using vite-plugin-ssr - [example template](https://github.com/brillout/vite-plugin-ssr/tree/main/examples/redux)) in order to pre-render pages for it using server-side-generation (SSG). That means I have       `plugins: [react(), ssr({ prerender: true })]` in my `vite-config.ts`, and there's no server running (besides a simple HTTP server).

I'm now following a [simple example](https://dev.to/igorovic/simplest-way-to-persist-redux-state-to-localstorage-e67) that saves the store in localStorage when it changes. When app is reloaded in a browser, I load any previous store from localStorage and apply it, so as to preserve the user's state.

**Problem**

Although the app loads its previous state correctly, I'm running into hydration errors, because (I assume) I'm setting the localStorage-loaded store too early:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <form> in <div>.
    at form
    at FormWithFirstName (eval at a (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-live-runner.js?v=6e40a83a:22645:10), <anonymous>:7:43)
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-live-runner.js?v=6e40a83a:22669:5)
    at div
    at w (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-live-runner.js?v=6e40a83a:26441:20)
    at div
    at div
    at Split2 (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-split-it.js?v=6e40a83a:2414:9)
    at div
    at j (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-live-runner.js?v=6e40a83a:26431:19)
    ...
```

... and:

```
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js:12507:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js:12535:7)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:19902:5)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21618:14)
    ...
```

I think the simplest approach would be to simply delay setting the store from localStorage until after the client has done initializing. I don't mind using a manual delay of (say) 0.5s.

**File Structure**

I have **_default.page.client.tsx**, which listens for changes to the store, saves them, and loads them:

```jsx
...
import { saveState, loadState } from './src/app/browser-storage';

async function render(pageContext: PageContextClient) {
  const { Page, pageProps } = pageContext
  
  // Get the store that was in localStorage and use that:
  const store = getStore(loadState());

  // Create a listener to save the store in localStorage:
  store.subscribe(
    debounce(() => {
      saveState(store.getState());
    }, 800)
  );  
  
  if (!Page) throw new Error('Client-side render() hook expects pageContext.Page to be defined')
  const root = document.getElementById('react-root')
  if (!root) throw new Error('DOM element #react-root not found')
  hydrateRoot(
    root,
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PageShell pageContext={pageContext}>
        <Page {...pageProps} />
      </PageShell>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

- `loadState()` is a utility function which pulls the serialized store from localStorage.
- `saveState()` is a utility function which saves the store to localStorage.

Here's a simplified view of **App.tsx**

```jsx
function App() {
  const code = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.chat.code);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    InitializeGoogleAnalytics();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <LiveProvider code={code} scope={scope}>
        <div className="leftContentContainer">
          {/* @ts-ignore TS2322 */}
          <Split direction="vertical">
            <LivePreview style={{ padding: '10px' }} />
            <LiveEditor style={{ minHeight: '100%', fontFamily: 'monospace' }} />
          </Split>
        </div>
        <div className="errorContainer" style={{ }} >
          <LiveError style={{ height: '100%', marginTop: '0px'}}/>
        </div>
      </LiveProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

In this case, `code` is a property that's being pulled from the store.

Since this is an SSR application, App is used by a **pages/index/index.page.tsx**.

```jsx
import App from '../../App';

export { Page }
      
function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <App />
    </>
  )
}
```

What's the best way to set the store after a manual delay?